# get unchecked checkboxes values in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a form that allows users to select what notifications they want to receive, it then stores this information into the database. What I realized is that there are currently about 10 options / notifications that users can receive, so saving 10 options into the database for every user, is going to fill up the database pretty quick.

Instead i'd like to make it so that it only stores the type of notifications into the database that they do *not* want to receive.

At the moment, jQuery only sends values of the checkboxes checked, not the values of the checkboxes not checked.

Does any one else have a better solution or have any ideas on how I can send the unchecked values, or maybe create it so unchecked = "off" and checked = "on"

### jQuery

```js
var data = $('#notificationsform').serializeArray();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: base_url + "/api/save_notification_preferences",
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    if (response.status == "success") {
      console.log(data.message);


      $('#successtxt').html(data.message);
      $('#success-snack').addClass('snackbar-active');

      setTimeout(function () {
        $('#success-snack').removeClass('snackbar-active');
      }, 1500)

      $(".close-article").click();
    } else {
      $('#errortxt').html(data.message);
      $('#error-snack').addClass('snackbar-active');
    }
  }
});
```

### HTML

Just a quick note `notifications[]` currently means email notifications and `inapp[]` should mean they want / dont want to receive in app notifcations

```html
<form id="notificationsform">
  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Review Activity</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="notifications[]"
      value="reviews"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />

    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="inapp[]"
      value="reviews"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Feed Activity</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      value="feed"
      name="notifications[]"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      value="feed"
      name="inapp[]"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Someone follows me</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="notifications[]"
      value="follows"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="inapp[]"
      value="follows"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Important updates</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="notifications[]"
      value="updates"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="inapp[]"
      value="updates"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Brunch Invites</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="notifications[]"
      value="invites"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="inapp[]"
      value="invites"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Event Notifications</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="notifications[]"
      value="events"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="inapp[]"
      value="events"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Invite requests</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="notifications[]"
      value="inviterequests"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="inapp[]"
      value="inviterequests"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Invite Status changes</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="notifications[]"
      value="invitestatus"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="inapp[]"
      value="invitestatus"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="boxit">
    <span>Other social notifications</span>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="notifications[]"
      value="othersocial"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 8px;"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="inapp[]"
      value="othersocial"
      style="float: right; top: -31px; margin-right: 46px;"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```php
$notifications = $this->input->post('notifications');
$me = is_user_logged_in();

$delete1 = "DELETE FROM `notificationssettings` WHERE  userID ='$me' ";
$this->db->query($delete1);

foreach ($this->input->post('notifications') as $key => $bg):
  $insertnotifications['type'] = $bg;
  $insertnotifications['userID'] = is_user_logged_in();
  $this->db->insert("notificationssettings", $insertnotifications);
endforeach;

$data = [
  'status' => 'success',
  'data' => [
    'message' => "Notification settings saved succesfully.",
  ],
];
echo json_encode($data);

exit();
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox): "_Note: If a checkbox is unchecked when its form is submitted, there is no value submitted to the server to represent its unchecked state (e.g. value=unchecked); the value is not submitted to the server at all. If you wanted to submit a default value for the checkbox when it is unchecked, you could include an <input type="hidden"> inside the form with the same name and value, generated by JavaScript perhaps._"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecked checkbox values simply aren't sent to the server.

However, since you know what the possible options are, you can make your PHP backend aware of the possible options, and can then compare the list of known options against what comes in through the POST request.

```php
<?php

// ...

$POSSIBLE_NOTIFICATIONS = [
  'reviews',
  'feed',
  'follows',
  'updates',
  'invites',
  'events',
  'inviterequests',
  'invitestatus',
  'othersocial'
];

$notifications_opted_in = $this->input->post('notifications');
$notifications_opted_out = array_diff($POSSIBLE_NOTIFICATIONS, $notifications_opted_in);
```